# Projection of raster to sinusoidal projection

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, reprojection-mathematics

I have my definitive raster shown below. This raster has the projection as mentioned [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/modis-sinusoidal-3/)

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 7276, 8330, 60609080  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 463.3127, 463.3127  (x, y)
extent      : 6508617, 10368012, 751956.5, 4123020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : <address path of where this raster is stored>
names       : <definitive raster>
values      : 0, 578  (min, max)
```

I have another land use land cover raster (each pixel value being categorical) that is in WGS1984 coordinate system i.e. no projection. I want project this raster to the same projection as the definitive raster to do more analysis.

I did so in R as follows

```
lulc_reproj<-projectRaster(lulc_, res=res(defintive raster),crs=crs(definitive raster), method='ngb')
```

It did complete with no errors and I could continue with my analysis. However, I viewed the projected lulc raster and the definitive raster in Arc and see that two rasters do not align. For example, below is a snapshot of the water class in the reprojected lulc raster (light blue) which is way off from the water in the definitive raster (which is NoData and displayed in red)
[image]

The same is the case when viewed in QGIS. Like I mentioned earlier, no errors come up in R and the projection strings match additional to the resolution.

I also tried projecting the lulc raster in ArcMap as I have read that Arc uses different transformation algorithms than gdal, on which rgdal and raster packages are based. However, I get the exact same results i.e. no alignment

So why are the rasters not aligned even if they have the same projections and resolutions? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the image you posted the full extent of the data you reprojected? If not, is the apparent shift the same over the whole region?

Comment: @Spacedman it is not the entire extent, I zoomed in to show an example of the water bodies. Yes, I think the shift is the same over the entire region.

Comment: Could you measure the size of the shift - there's no scale on your map. Sorry, should have asked before.

Comment: I used the measure tool in Arc and the shift is approximately 40 km.

Comment: I overlaid the projected lulc imagery (light blue above) over a basemap of imagery in Arc and see that the water bodies sit on top of each other perfectly. So now I think that that projectRaster() and writeRaster() messed up another time with a projection!